# Is it possible to compile and execute project with java modules in pycharm ide?

Tags: java, pycharm, ide

I have a project with different modules. All those modules are written in Python and hence using Pycharm as an IDE. Now a new module need to be added written in Java. Is Pycharm be used in this case or need to use different IDE for Java module? Am I be able to compile and execute the Java code same way that we do in IDE like eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm does not support Java, use [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) + Python plugin instead ([community](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7322-python-community-edition) / [professional](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/631-python)).